# How to install a .jar file

Tags: software-installation, minecraft

I would like to know how to install java and minecraft ([Download Linux Version Here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/launcher/Minecraft.jar))

Comment: You can't really 'install' a tgz or jar file. A tgz is just an archive, as well as a jar. You could manually install it, but not with the default Debian/Ubuntu package manager. You will need to install Java from the software center. For minecraft, download the file, and extract it if needed. Then just read the instructions or find the file you need to use to install or launch the program. Perhaps you would benefit from reading the Ubuntu manual: http://ubuntu-manual.org/

Answer (score 20):

You must installed java on your system to install `.jar` files.Syntax to install .jar files was,

```
java -jar packagename.jar
```

In this case,you have Minecraft.jar file,so type the below command in terminal

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

Comment: ok. Do you play minecraft?

Answer (score 1):

A .jar file is a Java Programming Language file. You can do this, since it's Minecraft:

1. Create a new folder in your user folder. (It can also be recognized as a "~".)
2. Move Minecraft and an icon (call it "Minecraft" and make sure it's a .png, and if not, convert it using an online tool.) to a folder you will keep it in. Use `~/.apps/Minecraft`, for the sake of usage.
3. Make a file, on your desktop. Create a new file, name it "Minecraft.desktop". More info [here](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en).
   Copy-and-paste this after you open it with a text editor:

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=Minecraft
   Exec=java -jar ~/.apps/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar
   Icon=~/.apps/Minecraft/Minecraft.png
   Type=Application
   Categories=Game;
   ```
4. Do this in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install default-jre
   chmod +x ~/.apps/Minecraft/Minecraft.jar
   chmod +x ~/Desktop/Minecraft.desktop
   ```
5. Now, double-click and play!

Answer (score 0):

**Install .tgz file**

1. first you need to extract the archive. Command is;

   `sudo tar xzvf Example.tgz`

   or you can *right click* the file and give "Extract Here" option in Menu.
2. Then read and follow the README or INSTALL text file inside the extracted archive to install.

   Most of the time, the steps to install are 1. `./configure` 2. `make` 3. `make install`

   (You need to run them inside the folder directory of the extracted archive.)

Or you can open the file via *Synaptic Package Manager* and install through it.

**Install .jar file**

.jar files actually *not needed to install*. Just need *open with* ***java*** to run.

Right click the file and select "Open with java(-6/7/8)-openjdk" in menu. Or you need to select "Properties" and select to open with java.

If in command line, can open with `xdg-open Example.jar` or `java -jar Example.jar`