# How to install dli-downloader into Linux?

Tags: command-line, software-installation, jar

I want to install [dli-downloader](https://code.google.com/p/dli-downloader/) into Ubuntu. Provide step by step guide. With JDK configuration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install a .jar file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/372762/how-to-install-a-jar-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install JAVA

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Then download `dli-downloader with dependancies` package, to your /home

```
wget https://dli-downloader.googlecode.com/files/dli-downloader-5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Then you can run

```
java -jar ~/dli-downloader-5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Dli-Downloader will now run

You can make a "clickable" executable by opening `gedit` and pasting this into a new file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=java -jar ~/dli-downloader-5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false
Name=Dli-Downloader
Comment=Runs Dli downloder
```

Save it in /home as

```
dli.desktop
```

Then make it executable

```
chmod -x ~/dli.desktop
```

Now if you click `dli.desktop` dli-downloader will start.

Comment: madhavnikam@madhavnikam-Aspire-E5-511:~/Desktop/1$ java -jar ~/dli-downloader-5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/madhavnikam/dli-downloader-5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: yes! i exact copy commands.

Comment: Its ok, right click `/Desktop/dli-downloader-5.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar` choose properties, then permissions and mark as executable

Comment: ohh! i really sorry that error occur because of directory path. problem. working now. thanks.

Comment: No worries, please accept if it worked